# How do you prevent a function from starting if the others do not pass?

Tags: javascript, html

Basically I have this function containing other functions:

```
function allFunctions() {
    inputCheck();
    confirmTextFields();
    sizeSelect();
    checkScrollList();
    checkCheckBoxes();
    displayTotal();
}
```

All of these functions ultimately only pop up if a user doesn't do something correctly via `windows.alerts` and confirms.

What I want to happen is that if the user has an error and the alert comes up saying what the error is, once they press "Ok", I want `displayTotal()` to not run. If everything is correct, then `displayTotal()` can run.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

EDIT: These are the functions above: http://pastebin.com/KzMNaT0s

Comment: You don't return true from a lot of those functions.

Comment: I mean they all worked for what I was aiming for at first, but then I had a change of plans and ya..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should let each function return a true or a false indicating if they were successful. Then you can use those return values to determine is displayTotal() should run.

The function was called like this:

```
 <input type="submit" value="Order" name="order" onclick="allFunctions()" />
```

that must be changed to

```
 <input type="submit" value="Order" name="order" onclick="return allFunctions()" />
```

And edit allFunctions like this:

```
function allFunctions() {
    var successful = true;
    successful &= inputCheck();
    successful &= confirmTextFields();
    successful &= sizeSelect();
    successful &= checkScrollList();
    successful &= checkCheckBoxes();
    if(successful) {
        displayTotal();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

http://pastebin.com/FANCaYgN
See the pastebin for the functions with proper return values.

Comment: Fixed the returns in the functions and then tried the allFunctions() above and the page just submitted with a blank form (which would make an alert for a blank field).

Comment: In what function do you check for a blank field?

Comment: confirmTextFields(). Basically I didn't fill anything out, just to see the alerts come up, but the page just submitted. It didn't run any of the functions.

Comment: Try it now, I added an extra else statement to prevent the submit from happening

Comment: Still going straight to my submit html form :p

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96446/discussion-between-xeli-and-rockguitarist1).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you implement something like that:

```
function allFunctions() {
    inputCheck() &&
    confirmTextFields() &&
    sizeSelect() &&
    checkScrollList() &&
    checkCheckBoxes() &&
    displayTotal();
}
```

That works if the functions return `true` if correctly run without errors and `false` if an error occured. In the last case the short circuit is closed and the processing is stopped.

Comment: Tried this and the alert came up, but as soon as I click "Ok" the page submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a variable where you can store each functions result and compare that after all validations have completed.

```
function allFunctions() {
        var result;
        result = inputCheck();
        result &= confirmTextFields();
        result &= sizeSelect();
        result &= checkScrollList();
        result &= checkCheckBoxes();
        if (result)
            displayTotal();
    }
```

This of course relies on the particular functions returning a bool value.

For instance:

```
function inputCheck() {
    if (true) {
        //Successful
        return true;
    }
    else {
        //Unsuccessful
        return false;
    }
}
```

And with a little error handling:

```
function allFunctions() {
    try {
        var result;
        result = inputCheck();
        result &= confirmTextFields();
        result &= sizeSelect();
        result &= checkScrollList();
        result &= checkCheckBoxes();
        if (result)
            displayTotal();
    }
    catch(ex) {
        alert('Oops, there has been a problem\n\n' + ex.message);
    }
}
```

Then you can go a little more advanced if you're so sadistically inclined, for instance:

```
function inputCheck() {
    try {
        if (true) {
            //Successful
            return true;
        }
        else  {
            throw new exception("User field empty");
        }
    }
    catch(ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

PS: If you don't need the postback may I suggest you change your markup to:

```
<input type="submit" value="Order" name="order" onclick="allFunctions();return false;" />
```

From what I'm seeing you can handle everything with ajax.